# C# setting dynamic attribute value in validation attribute error message

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am fetching my Error messages from a table in DB , it has an errorText and an errorKey.

it throws up error

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Comment: What class contains the `public string attribute{ get; set; }` property you are validating via attribute there? From the top of my head the concept of dynamic error messages like that require a dynamic validation model, ruling out attributes. Have you considered something like FluentValidation (https://fluentvalidation.net/) or other dynamic validators?

Comment: Attributes can not have property values dynamically assigned. That's why you are getting this error. Can you explain what exact problem you are trying to solve by doing this? Why you can not use resource files and resource names instead of stirring error messages in the database?

Comment: well i have a client requirement he does not want to use the resource file or localization etc, the only thing he wants that he should only update message in db and they should reflect in code.

Comment: @gerryc.inc its just an example of attribute reside in some DTO